# Meteor server unicode channel problem

Tags: http, http-headers, utf-8

When trying to subscribe to a channel named "public" with [Meteor](http://meteorserver.org/), a specialised web server for real-time push using [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), I get
the desired response:

```
<script>ch("public",0)</script>
```

When the http request is:

```
GET /push/131530959548387383/xhrinteractive/public?nc=1315309595740 HTTP/1.1
```

But when i try to subscribe to a channel named in english and hebrew such as:
"tag-קוקאין" and the http request is:

```
GET /push/1315309516300999786/xhrinteractive/tag-%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F?nc=1315309516590 HTTP/1.1
```

I get an akward response - the name of the channel became dots:

```
<script>ch("tag-............", 0);</script>
```

The file that is responsible of figuring out the header uses this regex:

```
if($self->{'headerBuffer'}=~/GET\s+$::CONF{'SubscriberDynamicPageAddress'}\/([0-9a-z]+)\/([0-9a-z]+)\/([a-z0-9_\-\%\.\/]+).*?/i)
    {
        $self->{'subscriberID'}=$1;
        $self->{'mode'}=$2;
        my $persist=$self->getConf('Persist');
        my $maxTime=$self->getConf('MaxTime');
        $self->{'ConnectionTimeLimit'} = ($self->{'ConnectionStart'}+$maxTime) if ($maxTime>0);

        my @channelData=split('/',$3);
        my $channels={};
        my $channelName;
        my $offset;
        foreach my $chandef (@channelData) {
            if($chandef=~/^([a-z0-9_\-\%]+)(.(r|b|h)([0-9]*))?$/i) {
                $channelName = $1;
                $channels->{$channelName}->{'startIndex'} = undef;
                if ($3) {
                   $offset = $4;
                   if ($3 eq 'r') { $channels->{$channelName}->{'startIndex'} = $offset; }
                   if ($3 eq 'b') { $channels->{$channelName}->{'startIndex'} = -$offset; }
                   if ($3 eq 'h') { $channels->{$channelName}->{'startIndex'} = 0; }
                }
            }
        }
```

I might add that Meteor is a comet server of it's own. it's
purpose is to push notifications in real time:
[meteorserver.org](http://meteorserver.org)

There has to be a fix for this somewhere.. i tried searching everywhere with no avail.
I will be grateful if someone will point me to some direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you linked to a page describing what Meteor is - RSS reader, application, web server?

And provide some details, e.g. does Meteor claim to support UTF-8, and have you configured it to do so?  Also what platform are you on, and is this a client or server app?

The first character (%D7%A7) in the 2nd URL given above is the UTF-8 encoding (D7 A7) of [this Hebrew character](http://www.tachyonsoft.com/uc0005.htm#U05E7) - probably what's happening is that the GET is being correctly encoded in UTF-8 (the default for modern browsers and client apps), but the response either is not valid UTF-8, or the client application doesn't recognise it as UTF-8.

**Update 1**:

- The code looks like Perl, which does have Unicode support, but Unicode-enabling a Perl application is not always a simple task.  However it is possible to do it in portions e.g. just have that regex `$chandef=~/^([a-z0-9_\-\%]+)(.(r|b|h)([0-9]*))?$/i` match a UTF-8 alphanumeric etc string - see the Encode CPAN module and similar encode/decode builtins, as long as you are using Perl 5.8+ and preferably 5.10+.  Any time you see `[a-z]` in code, it's a red flag for internationalisation and Unicode.  This is turning into a StackOverflow answer so I'll stop there...
- You haven't answered my 2nd and 3rd questions but the code makes it clear that Meteor won't support UTF-8 without some code changes.
- You really need to talk to the Meteor developers as this is quite specific to this server, see http://meteorserver.org/how-to-join-in/

Comment: Thanks @RichVel for responding and sorry for that, i have edited the question.